# Parse.com PHP SDK - Refresh user data - Fetch command

Tags: javascript, php, ios, parse-platform, sdk

I'm using the Parse.com PHP SDK on one of my pages. I seem to have a similar problem I faced on the iOS version but I easily solved that using the 'fetch' command.

The problem is when I edit information in my database, it does not update on my web page when I refresh the page. The user has to log out then log back in for the new data to be shown.

Here is how I'm getting the data:

```
<?php $u1=ParseUser::getCurrentUser()->get("auto"); echo $u1; ?>
```

Here is the documentation on the 'fetch' command but I don't understand how it works or how it is implemented: http://parseplatform.org/parse-php-sdk/classes/Parse.ParseUser.html#method_fetch

Does anyone know how to show the updated string values using this command or anything similar that would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is a *cached object* in your current session, specifically the current `ParseUser`. You can see that the php sdk attempts to [find the current user](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-php-sdk/blob/master/src/Parse/ParseUser.php#L515) from a variety of places, all effectively independent of the server-side copy.

You were in the right direction, you can use the `fetch` method to 'refresh' any `ParseObject` by updating it with any new changes from the database:

```
// get the current user
$user = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();

// fetch changes from parse
$user->fetch();

// get your newly set key/value pair
$isAuto = $user->get('auto');
```

Your user object will then be refreshed with the changes you need.

Comment: Thanks for that but I got a fatal error: "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /xxx/index.php on line 22"

Comment: I somehow removed the error, I may have misplaced it but now I have the issue of my user being logged out as soon as I trigger fetch?

Comment: Yeah where ever I seem to add the fetch command, it automatically logs my user out of the page completely. How do I avoid being logged out?

Comment: The non-object issue is indicating that whatever you're trying to call `fetch` on is not a `ParseObject`, can always debug with `var_dump` to see if you have **null** for instance. Your user should not be logged out when triggering fetch, unless the session is somehow being revoked in the process. I would double check and make sure that you're properly setting up a session in advance via `session_start()` before setting up the sdk.

Comment: I have session_start() on all pages, I have used fetch as the initial function on-load and it keeps logging out the user

Comment: Here is my source code on the top of my page. Without the 'fetch' command, the user is logged in from login.php and everything else shows up just fine. With the fetch, the user is never detected and is logged out. Source: https://pastebin.com/S8sSTgc5

Comment: I also just highlighted the redirect headers and noticed as the page loads, none of my data loads. It really does log the user out when I use the fetch command..

Comment: Here's some [feedback](https://pastebin.com/e7F1HYUD). As far as `fetch` goes, it does nothing to the current session. You can take a look [here](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-php-sdk/blob/master/src/Parse/ParseObject.php#L521) to see for yourself. If I were to make a guess there's an error somewhere else in your code. If `fetch` causes an error it may have something to do with `$currentUser` not being what you think it is. Especially since you mentioned a `non-object` error before I would be double checking that.

Comment: Many thanks for that but my issue was not resolved at all. What I showed you is my entire source code. I have nothing else added. I have made the adjustments you suggested and my user was not logged out (since I guess fetch was never triggered as its in a new if statement). Now later down the code, I try to retrieve some info and do the following: <p class="user-roal"><?php  $currentUser->fetch();  $u1 = $currentUser->get("validuntill"); echo $u1; ?> Member</p> - NOTHING shows up as soon as I add the fetch in, it shows fine without it but its cached and not new..

Comment: Hmmm, when you say nothing shows up are you saying the entire page fails to load when that code fires? If that's the case you may be getting an exception, something that's preventing the code from continuing to execute. If you haven't already I would double check your error logs, you might just find something there.

Comment: Also a quick note I did check your code locally against a test instance of parse-server and it did seem to work just fine.

Comment: Nothing shows up in the sense of no data is pulled at all. My <p> shows nothing. As soon as I removed the fetch command it works just fine.. The fetch command seems to be either logging my user out or simply destroying the data and not actually catching the new records properly.

Comment: The page loads just fine, without the fetch command, no new data is pulled. With the fetch command, no data at all is pulled. Any ideas? Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: Ahh, so the object is still there then it seems, just missing the properties we're looking for. To confirm your suspicions I would try running `$currentUser->_encode()` before and after `fetch` and compare the results. If the data fetched from the server is missing or empty you'll be able to directly see that in `_encode` return data. That might help narrow things down a bit. And no problem!

Comment: <?php $currentUser->_encode(); $currentUser->fetch(); $currentUser-
      >_encode(); $u1 = $currentUser->get("validuntill"); echo $u1; ?> 
      Member</p>

Comment: Still did not work, no change. As soon as I include fetch it simply either logs the user out on page reload or shows up with no data.

Comment: Is there anything else I can do? I can't seem to find absolutely any examples or articles on this at all

Comment: You need to `echo` or `var_dump` the return of `_encode`, this is to show what the properties of `$currentUser` are at the given time. By calling it you're not doing anything, it's purely for logging and breaking down what's going on. We have [docs](http://docs.parseplatform.org/php/guide/) by the way.